# POST - Can I include the raw Body Data in Post URL request?

Tags: rest, post, postman

Can I add raw data to the Post URL Request?

for example:

```
HTTP://token.abc/v1/oatuh2/rest/token{"OrgID: ABC", "sport:basketball"}
```

image below is from postman for understanding

[image: image below is from postman for understanding]

Comment: Don't know why you need that, but it's similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71711930/how-to-add-json-from-body-in-the-query-parameter/71714569#71714569

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17 I have an application that can be configured for any Web API to fetch data. One of the customers provided an API that requires a JSON string to be passed in MessageBody. The application does not have the option to add a JSON string to be added as a Message Body in the configuration. 

I and wondering if that JSON string can be passed as a part of the URL.

Comment: Thanks, Lucas! I tried to do as suggested in the link you provided but it did not work. I think what I'm asking is not doable. Cheers!